# check-types or check-lint similar command to stylelint

Tags: stylelint

When running a lint like Eslint, I can use the command `npm run check-lint` to check all the code on my project. The same goes with `npm run check-types` from typescript. Is there a similar command with stylelint? I didn't find anything on their docs about it. I know there is a --fix flag, but that's not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are [*npm run scripts*](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script), and unrelated to Stylelint itself. You can use *run scripts* to run any arbitrary command from a package's `"scripts"` object.

For example, to add a `check-styles` command to your project you should edit your `package.json` file and add:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "check-styles": "stylelint \"**/*.css\""
  }
}
```

You'll then be able to use `npm run check-styles`.